# Pass javascript function data into hidden form field and send result as url variable

Tags: javascript, forms, url, variables, input

I am trying to pass a javascript variable into a form field and send the result as a url variable, but I'm stuck with this code. Any help is appreciated. The code outputs the browser width viewport into a field field and this is then sent to the url as a variable when the form is submitted

```
  <html>
  <script>

   function getViewport() {

   var viewPortWidth;
   var viewPortHeight;

   window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
   if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
      viewPortWidth = window.innerWidth,
      viewPortHeight = window.innerHeight
   }
   return viewPortWidth;
}

 </script>

  <form action ='echo.php' method = 'GET'>
   <table>
    <tr>

     <td>

      <input type='hidden' name='r_w' onsubmit='this.value=getViewport();'>

     <td>

    <td>
     <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Go" />

    </td>

   </tr>


  </table>


 </form>


 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "onsubmit" event for a hidden input field. You would have to put that on the submit button and set the value of the field named "r_w" to the result of getViewport().

**Update**

Don't name your submit button "submit", it will throw off any calls to the form's submit functionality, which is what you're going to use here.

`<input type="submit value="Go" onsubmit="setViewPort()">`

Then create a function setViewPort() that sets the value of the field "r_w" to the result of getviewPort().

Comment: Thanks. How would you do that? something like this?                                                           <input type='hidden' name='r_w' 'this.value = getViewport();'>